# Css Transitions one after another

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I tried to make the `CSS transitions` to play one after other ,means first it has to transform the width and later height.
I tried with couple of options but everything is in vain.I achieved this in the `javascript` But can some `CSS`professionals help to explore this and break it up.Thanks in advance.

```
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height:500px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use the `transition-delay` property in the `transition` shorthand to do multiple transitions in sequence in one CSS rule.

```
-webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s ease 2s;
transition: width 2s, height 2s ease 2s;
```

Answer (score 10):

Break up the individual transition properties into comma-separated values for ease of reference....then just use transition delay to sequence them.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition-property: width, height;
    transition-duration:2s, 4s;
    transition-delay:0s, 2s;
    transition-timing-function:linear;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) for this.

```
/* Standard */
@keyframes all {
    0%   {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
    50%  {width: 300px; height: 100px;}
    100% {width: 300px; height: 500px;}
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes all {
    0%   {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
    50%  {width: 300px; height: 100px;}
    100% {width: 300px; height: 500px;}
}
```

Call it like this:

```
div:hover {
    -webkit-animation: all 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: all 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

See this example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdt4cykp/)

Edit: The other answers posted before me use a better method than this, as they can be used to reverse the animation when the user rolls over the div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer